# Get the most recent posts from a list of following firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, promise

I'm trying to get a list of posts from people a user follows ordered by how recent the post was posted. So no matter who posted, as long as the user is following them, the most recent posts from that collection of users would be seen first. I've tried this (it's not completely correct, just trying to get concept down):

```
// get all the users you are following -- this will count for a lot of reads if they follow 3000 people
    const following = await db
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userHandle)
        .collection('following')
        .get()

    // get the first 10 posts from those users ordered by recently posted
    const promises = following.map((doc) => {
        return db
            .collection('posts')
            .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
            .where('userHandle', '==', doc.data().userHandle)
            .limit(10)
            .get()
            .then(async (data) => {
               return data.docs.map((doc) => {
                  return {
                         postId: doc.id,
                         userHandle: doc.data().userHandle,
                         userImageUrl: doc.data().userImageUrl,
                         imageUrl: doc.data().imageUrl,
                         likeCount: doc.data().likeCount,
                         };
               })
            })
    });

    Promise.all(promises)
        .then((posts) => {
            res.json(posts);
        })
```

Problem with the above concept... this will return a lot of posts if the user follows a bunch of users. That limit is only for the amount of posts for one user that can be returned on that page. Also it would return 10 posts from one user recent to oldest, then 10 posts from the next user recent to oldest even though there has been more recent posts. I was thinking of maybe adding a counter where if the amount of posts returned is more than 10, stop the function and just return those 10, but I was having problems with promising before where the function returns null so that's why i return everything when i'm done looping using promise.all. Will this work? That may solve the limit problem, but not getting the absolute most recent post from a collection of the users that the current user is following. I wish firestore had a large query where I can just get all the recent posts that have a username that matches to one of the usernames in a following array (which could be returned from the following function at the top of the above code). Pretty sure I'm only allowed to check 10 values though if I just converted the username field to an array.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I'm understanding correctly, you want to get posts from people whom the user follows, and you want to get them sorted by time. Then, I would suggest you do this :

First, save the following list of your user in an array , like `following: ['celeb1','celeb2']`.

Then save all the posts in a collection, which has documents like

```
{
   content: 'some content',
   author: 'celeb1',
   time: 1598681888  //timestamp or whatever you like
   //some more props
}
```

And when you want to get posts for your user, just do

```
//Get the array contains all folloing people
let following = await db.collection('users').doc(userHandle).get();

//Get the first 10 posts from following people
let posts = await db.collection('posts').where('author', 'in',
following.data().following).limit(10).orderBy('time', 'desc').get();
```

Check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?authuser=1#array_membership) for more on `in` query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Wouldn’t I only be able to add up to 10 strings in that following array. “ Use the in operator to combine up to 10 equality (==) clauses on the same field with a logical OR.” Like that array wouldn’t be able to contain more than 10 users.

Comment: yes, it is a limitation of this implementation. I honestly didn't think about it when I first wrote the answer, but I think the idea is good.

Comment: I think I’m just gonna store the users as an array and make a query for every 10 users and take it from there. Using cloud functions so it can handle it.

Comment: yea, that sounds reasonable to me